# How can I simulate the nodes of a Cloud using different Virtual Machines(Possibly by using some sort of Vmware) on a single machine?

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, vmware, virtual-network

I am aiming to create a simulation of a Cloud network on a single machine. I want to create different virtual machines on a single machine using some sort of a VmWare software. These different virtual machines(8-10 instances) will act as different nodes of the cloud. I have a website created in ASP.Net which downloads the file by dividing it into different fragments. I want the code and the virtual machines to run such that the file fragments will get stored onto the different VM's. Currently the code is such that it takes the file fragments and stores it onto different folders on the same hard disk. I want these VM's to be running at the same time. How can I implement this?

Comment: Try exploring OpenNebula for creating vms inside a single pc.

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)